# SQL reduce public server role

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions, readonly

This problem refers to Sql server Security Logins and Server Roles.

I am using SSMS v17.3.

The end result of my question is, ultimately i want to have a user with **readonly access to my database**.

I have created the new user gave him login name & password.
Also i gave him a user mapping --> therefore mapping him to my database as public & db_datareader for readonly.

The problem is that the user still has access to write and update to the database.

I have found some articles saying that the problem is the **public server role**.

How can i give reduced rights to the public server role and should i?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rights can come from the public roles (database or server) **if** and only **if** someone GRANTed rights to public.

Otherwise, the user has more rights because of GRANTs to that user

I would recommend you use these scripts to check permissions:

- https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_dbpermissions
- https://sqlstudies.com/free-scripts/sp_srvpermissions

Comment: This is a fresh install of the SQL Server so no access is granted to the public.

Comment: @panoskarajohn Why not check *everything* using the scripts I suggest? There clearly is *some* access granted. You are assuming a lot

Even something like local admin being added to SQL Server by default...

Comment: May i ask you sth more? Your queries work and are fine. What i am seeing though is that they take away the rights from other users which were granted the access even the sa. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have to use the parameters to limit the login you want

Comment: Yes that is what I did and used the public server group... This is starting to make no sense. If you read my question I say that I create a new use login with db_datareader.  But the user can still write. I believe this is due to the public server role and I take away the permissions. After that even my sa does not have access.